# Convert string into hour for calculation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, sqldatatypes

I have table columns having string values such as "10:00", "2:00"...

```
Start time    End time
"8:00"        "13:00"
"10:00"       "14:00"
```

I would like to convert it into hour and I could calculate differences between columns in hours. I have tried CAST() and TRIM() but nothing works. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQLData Management studio

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "hour" when you say "convert to hour"? There is no "hour" data type. Do you actually just want the difference between to text columns after converting to time? Are the minutes always zero? Does the time span ever cross over midnight? Please show the attempts you mentioned you've tried (even if they have errors).

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @InHour VARCHAR(5)='8:00';
DECLARE @InHour2 VARCHAR(5)='23:59';
SELECT CAST(@InHour AS TIME(0)),CAST(@InHour2 AS TIME(0))
```

It works

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.